# Cognos CM-SYS-5025

Tags: db2, cognos, cognos-10

I'm creating big active report of sets when i click save i'm getting error when adding any new item

CM-SYS-5025

Content Manager cannot update an object because of an unexpected content store database error.

Details :
The file system is full.. SQLCODE=-968, SQLSTATE=57011, DRIVER=3.63.123

I tried searching for solution but can't find any one faced this error before I'm unable to add new things in the report because when i click save i get this error

Many Thanks!!

Comment: CM is a content store error. An error message with SQLCODE in it is probably a SQL errror. It looks like your content store database has run out space. Do you have a DBA that can check out your database? What type of database is your content store running in?

Comment: DB2 database, I'm unable to save the report because of this error

Comment: I've added the DB2 tag. Maybe a DB2 person can help. You need to resolve the issue in your DB2 database to proceed.

Comment: The error message seems pretty clear: you have no space left on the filesystem(s) where the content store database is located. Talk to your DBA, showing her the error message and the SQLCODE.